# What is the difference between putting @Cache in Entities and @QueryHints in Queries?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-redis, spring-cache, redisson, second-level-cache

I'm using spring data jpa and hibernate.
I implement level 2 cache with redisson-hibernate.

Caching works when you put @QueryHints notation in Queries without @cache notation in Entities. In this case, what is the particular reason why we do not put @Cache notation in Entities?